# Transparent ViewController work with presentViewController, but not pushViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

```
let dialog: FriendCheckInDialogViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FriendCheckInDialogViewController") as! FriendCheckInDialogViewController
dialog.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
```

If I use

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(dialog, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Then transparency works. But `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` does not, so I cannot go back.

If I use

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dialog, animated: false)
```

Then background becomes black instead of transparent. But `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` works, so I can go back.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you want to present your view controller modally or part of a navigation stack?  If you use presentViewController then it is modal and you need to use dismissViewController. If use a navigation controller and stack then you can present on top of the previous view controller with transparency

Comment: @Paulw11 cool, works, thanks man. Make it an answer. New to iOS development, so didn't find this method that easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing different presentation styles.

If you present a view controller modally using `presentViewController`, then you can dismiss it using `dismissViewController`.  In this case you can present the view controller modally over the current view controller.

If you push a view controller onto the navigation controller stack, then you can pop that view controller back off, but the pushed view controller replaces the current view controller, so you can't expose it "underneath".